bitcoin address was given to sender - it was converted to bitcoin cash address and was sent to my bitcoin Coinbase wallet
So, the address bitcoin cash was sent to - when converted is my bitcoin address - anyway to retrieve? Please help - willing to pay $$

This question is similar to: Bitcoin Cash accidentally sent to Bitcoin address. Can I get them back?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Mine was on coin base and they do not support importation of private keys  -

Hi @TrishaShepard, were you expecting to be paid in Bitcoin or in Bitcoin Cash?

@murch I was expecting to be paid in bitcoin and
So I gave my bitcoin address - when I looked up where the money was sent to I didn’t recognize it but when I put it into the converter it was my bitcoin address - so the sender sent bitcoin cash - it shows complete on the blockchain-

@Murch do you think there is anyone that can help me or is it gone ?

This is probably a question that can best be answered by the Coinbase customer service. But also, I would complain to the sender that they didn’t pay you in the agreed upon manner.
